# Running flask app with celery and rabbitmq

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I have the following file structure for my Flask project

```
flask_app/
    my_app/
        - __init__.py
        auth/
            - __init__.py
            - emailing.py
            - flask_celery 
            - models.py
            - views.py
        static/
            - css/
            - js/
        templates/
            - base.html
            - home.html
            - login.html
            - first_pdf.html 
    - run.py
```

In the file emailing.py

```
from flask_mail import Message, Mail
from my_app import app
from my_app.auth.flask_celery import make_celery
from flask import render_template
import pdfkit
from my_app.auth.models import User

app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"] = "amqp://localhost:5672//"
celery = make_celery(app)
mail = Mail(app)


def sending_first_email(name, last_name):
    first_task.delay(name, last_name)
    return "Generated pdf and sent"

@celery.task(name="views.first_task")
def first_task(name, last_name):
    rendered = render_template("first_pdf.html", name=name, last_name=last_name)

    employee = User.query.filter_by(full_name=name + " " + last_name).first()
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)
    msg = Message("New oncoming employee", sender="help@abc.ac.za", 
                  recipients= [employee.manager_email_address])

    msg.attach("employee.pdf", "application/pdf", pdf)
    msg.body = "Please find attached the details of the employee"
    mail.send(msg)
    return "First Message has been sent"
```

Then we set up celery on flask_celery.py. My issue is now running the app. I first start rabbitmq server and then try the following command on the project root folder "flask_app"

```
celery -A emailing.celery worker --loglevel=info
```

I get an error "Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': No module named 'emailing'
" and when running the same command on this directory 'flask_app/my_app/auth', I get the following error
"Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': No module named 'my_app' ". Can I please get any help in fixing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `celery -A emailing worker --loglevel=info -Q views` in folder in directory flask_app/my_app/auth
Hope will help you!

Comment: Unfortunately It still gives the error "Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': No module named 'my_app' ". Thank you for your response